# Render Component in iframe using vuejs without src attribute

Tags: html, iframe, vue.js

```
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="100%">

</ifrme>
```

I want to render component in this iframe. Is there any option of creating html element or rendering component in iframe?

```
new Vue({
   el:'#frame',
   store:store,
   router:router,
   render: component
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can refer below link That helped me a lot.
Here is the link and the code snippets.

```js
Vue.component('i-frame', {
  render(h) {
    return  h('iframe', {
      on: { load: this.renderChildren }
    })
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    //freezing to prevent unnessessary Reactifiation of vNodes
    this.iApp.children = Object.freeze(this.$slots.default)
  },  
  methods: {
    renderChildren() {
      const children = this.$slots.default
      const body = this.$el.contentDocument.body      
      const el = document.createElement('DIV') // we will mount or nested app to this element
      body.appendChild(el)
      
      const iApp = new Vue({
        name: 'iApp',
        //freezing to prevent unnessessary Reactifiation of vNodes
        data: { children: Object.freeze(children) }, 
        render(h) {
          return h('div', this.children)
        },
      })
      
      iApp.$mount(el) // mount into iframe
      
      this.iApp = iApp // cache instance for later updates
      
      
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('test-child', {
  template: `<div>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <p>
  <slot/>
  </p>
  </div>`,
  props: ['title'],
  methods: {
    log:  _.debounce(function() {
      console.log('resize!')
    }, 200)
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const doc = this.$el.ownerDocument
      const win = doc.defaultView
      win.addEventListener('resize', this.log)
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    const doc = this.$el.ownerDocument
    const win = doc.defaultView
    win.removeEventListener('resize', this.log)
  }  
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dynamicPart: 'InputContent',
    show: false,
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/ohznser9/

Comment: Something that was not immediately clear to me at first is that the linked example by Linusborg does not use a real <iframe> in his template. He creates a custom component called "i-frame", which renders itself in an iframe. 

In other words, it doesn't directly show how to bind content to an iframe. It creates a component with behavior that hopefully does what you are looking for.

Comment: This works, but how to load CSS into the iframe. I'm trying to avoid making an css request in the iframe, any options to embed to style?

Comment: ye, we need to know how put CSS into iframe :)

Comment: any idea of hoW to do this in file components?

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-inside-iframe/6419 (Original thread of LinusBorgs fiddle)

Answer (score 20):

The easiest way for me is to use [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) attribute. It loads raw html overriding src attribute.

```html
<template>
    <iframe :srcdoc="html"></iframe>
</template>
```

Update: More detail example: Consider a textarea for a user `html` input and want to display in an `iframe`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <textarea v-model="html"></textarea>
    <iframe :srcdoc="html"></iframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data(){
    return {
      html:"<h1>Hello I am H1 block</h1>"
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Dead simple, and doesn't use unnecessary and complicating layers of abstraction.

Comment: I wish this had some more explanation, as well as the associated javascript code. I think `"html"` stands for a html fragment that is supposed to be supplied by vue somehow?

Comment: @abulka I updated my answer with more detail example, hope you understand. https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-haze-c0ydz?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 2):

I've tried and haven't found a way to mount vue directly on `#iframe`.

Yet, you can add `div` to `#iframe` and mount to that:

```
// create iframe element
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.id = 'iframe'
// place iframe inside page html
document.documentElement.insertBefore(iframe, document.querySelector('html').firstChild)

// append div to iframe
var container = document.createElement('div')
container.id = 'container'
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(container)

// render vue component inside iframe on #container
new Vue({
el: container,
render: h => h(component)
})
```

*Result:*

```
<html>
  <iframe id="iframe">
    #document
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body><!-- <-- here was <div id="container"></div> -->
        <div class="message" style="color: orange;">Hello from Vue component!</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </iframe>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.s. I've used this code in *chrome extension content scripts* (javascript injected into pages). If you're going to use
it elsewhere make sure not to break [Same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153).

Comment: I 'm having the same use case. Created the iframe and rendered the Vue components inside.  The styles of the components are not applied though. Do you have any recommendations for this ?

Comment: var extStyle = document.createElement('link');
extStyle.rel = 'stylesheet';  
extStyle.href = browser.extension.getURL("somestyle.css");  
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(extStyle);

Comment: @nteath did you ever solve this ?  Have exactly the same use case.Using the Vue CLI, the dev server/hot reload injects <style> tags into the parent document (where the JS runs) rather than into the iFrame document. Any pointers?

Comment: if container is a full document? `<html>...</html>`

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
el:'#frame',
store:store,
router:router,
render: component
})
```

just try to give a name to your route view.
Hope it works